# On first-order convexity conditions

Tags: convex-analysis

I have the following proposition:

> **Proposition 1.3** (Alternative form of the first-order convexity condition) 
>  The first-order convexity conditions $$ f({\bf y}) 
> \geq f({\bf x}) + ( {\bf y} - {\bf x} ) \cdot \nabla f( {\bf x}) $$ and $$ ( {\bf y} - {\bf x} ) \left( \nabla f( {\bf y}) - \nabla f( {\bf x}) \right) \geq 0 $$ are equivalent, where ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in D (f)$.

---

However, it comes without proof. The first implying the second is easy enough. However, I do not see how the second implies the first. I tried many things but I can't get away without assuming too much. I am at the point where I am not sure if they are equivalent.

**Question:** Is the given equivalence true, and if so, then how does one go about proving the backward direction?

Comment: Where does this proposition come from?

Comment: This is from lecture notes on a course on variational principles.

Comment: Is there a link to lecture slides?

Comment: These are adaptions from notes that I took. Are you asking by any chance because of the formating?

Comment: Not really. Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about convex functions of multiple variables can often be reduced to a question about convex functions of a single variable by considering that function on a line or segment between two points.

The two conditions are indeed equivalent for a differentiable function $f:D \to \Bbb R$ on a convex domain $D \subset \Bbb R^n$.

To prove that the second condition implies the first, fix two points $x, y \in D$ and define
$$
 l:[0, 1] \to D \, ,  \, l(t) = x + t (y-x) \, , \\
 g:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R\, , \,  g(t) = f(l(t)) \, .
$$

Note that
$$
 g'(t) = (y-x) \nabla f(l(t)) \, .
$$

For $0 < t < 1$ is
$$
 g'(t)- g'(0) = (y-x)\bigl(\nabla f(l(t)) - \nabla f(l(0) \bigr) \\
 = \frac{1}{t} \bigl(l(t)-l(0)\bigr) \bigl(\nabla f(l(t)) - \nabla f(l(0) \bigr) \ge 0 \, ,
$$
and the mean-value theorem gives, with some $\xi \in (0, 1)$,
$$
 f(x) - f(y) = g(1) -g(0) = g'(\xi) \ge g'(0) 
= (y-x) \nabla f(x) \, .
$$

(Actually, $g'$ is increasing so that $g$ is convex.)